# Git Merge Branch with nested branches

Tags: git, github

I have develop branch.
From develop we have auth branch (pull request from auth)
from auth we have level branch (pull request from auth)
from level we have class branch (pull request from level)

I already first merged auth into develop branch.
then level into auth
then class into level

How do I now merge level into develop branch so I have code from all the 3 branches (auth, level and class into develop)

Thank you.

Comment: Note that in Git, a branch name merely identifies *one particular commit*. Branch names never nest: there's no parent/child relationship with branch names. *Commits* have parent/child relationships, but `git merge` works by commit in the first place, so there's nothing special to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Since `auth` is already in develop, we can ignore that one. Since `class` is in `level` we can ignore that one. Then you only need to merge `level` into `develop`.

So you've to `git checkout develop` and then `git merge level`.